# Migrating SQL Server database to Firebase

Tags: sql-server

I am working on Flutter Mobile App. I am using SQL Server as my database. How do I actually export both its table and data from SQL Server to Firebase since Firebase is a NoSQL database.

I have tried to do export it to csv and converting it to JSON file, however, the csv file which have been exported do not contain the full SQL Server tables and data.

Comment: So the only problem is: _The csv file which have been exported do not contain the full SQL tables and data_  What method are you using to export the data? Obviously there is an issue there

Comment: I am using MSSQL SQL Server Export Wizard and it will auto generate a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

To export an entire table as JSON, try the following:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @json = (
  SELECT *
  FROM MyTable
  FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
)

SELECT @json

-- Export @json to a JSON file using BCP or other methods
```